# How to apply CSS filter to video without affecting controls in HTML5?

Tags: html, css, html5-video

If I apply a CSS filter to a video element, for example:

```css
  video:first-child {
    filter: brightness(40%);
  }
```

```html
<video controls></video> vs.
<video controls></video>
```

Then I find that the same effect applies to the media controls UI that the browser provides (via controls attribute on the video tag).

Are there any techniques that allow for applying the filter to the video content without the controls being affected?

Comment: Show some markup. You'll want to add a class name or ID to only the elements you want to be affected by the css, and apply the styles to only that class name or ID.

Comment: As the controls are a part of the video element, applying a class or id to elements won't help me target the filter any more specifically - the controls will still receive the same filter effect.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. Have you inspected elements to see if you can filter it further? Or you can add some kind of filtered dev over your video with a static position? You will need to provide something more for us to test with to help you because you haven't shown any markup or JS Fiddle or anything.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to make custom controls in this case. There is always clip mask/path that *might* work but the size of it will vary from browser to browser, and from time from time...

Answer (score 3):

Don't think this is possible, but you could make your own play/pause buttons etc using javascript, then style the video? Like below:-

```js
(function (window, document, $, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#play').on('click', function(){
            $('.my-video')[0].play();
        });
        $('#stop').on('click', function(){
            $('.my-video')[0].pause();
        });
    });


})(window, document, jQuery);
```

```css
video {
    border: 10px solid green !important;
    opacity: 0.6;
    box-shadow: 12px 9px 13px rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<video width="320" height="240" class="my-video">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</div>
<button type="button" id="play">Play</button>
<button type="button" id="stop">Stop</button>
```